# Twitter Bootstrap TypeAhead with PlusAsTab

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I have a form(HTML) in which I want to navigate through the elements using Enter Key (Enter Key should act like Tab).  To achieve this functionality I have used the [PlusAsTab](https://github.com/joelpurra/plusastab) library.  Also I need autocomplete feature on one of the textbox.  For AutoComplete Feature I am using TypeAhead from Twitter Bootstrap.

So I am using PlusAsTab and Twitter Bootstrap Together.
Now the PlusAsTab Navigation using the Enter Key is working fine with elements other then those associated with TypeAhead.  For the Elements associated with TypeAhead I need to press the Enter twice to navigate.  I tried to debug but not successful.  I am quite new to Javascript hence not able to debug it properly.

**Please find the code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prdinesh/qMtfA/6/).**

I have attached the code here too for convenience

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Trial</title>
 <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class="plus-as-tab form-inline" id="transtable">
<select class="span1" autofocus="autofocus"><option>Dr</option><option>Cr</option></select>
<select class="span4">
    <option>SelectAccount</option>
    <option>GodAccount</option>
    <option>SundryCreditors</option>
    <option>SundryDebtors</option>
    <option>Capital</option>
    <option>Cash</option>
    <option>Sales</option>
</select>
 <input type="text" class="span4" placeholder="Narration" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["ChequeNo : ","Account No : ","No : ","On Canara Bank : " ]'>

<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on">Rs</span><input class="span3" size="12" type="text" onchange="nextrow(this)" onkeypress="return allowonlynum(event)">
</div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://joelpurra.github.com/plusastab/lib/emulatetab/src/emulatetab.joelpurra.js"></script>
<script src="http://joelpurra.github.com/plusastab/src/plusastab.joelpurra.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
​
```

Please help me to debug this problem further.

Comment: I have the code in JSFiddle, I have given the link above.  May be it is not clear.  I will attach the code here too.

Comment: ah, yes. my mistake, I missed that link the first time.

Comment: I did some more analysis today.  My observation is as follows <br/>1.when the Enter Key is pressed the control moves from the current control to the next control.  But the Bootstrap Typeahead is not accepting the focus of the element, instead it just added a <ul> element at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my Friend I have temporarily solved this problem.  In the [PlusAsTab](https://github.com/joelpurra/plusastab) library I have added one more call to focus the next element, ie., it will try to focus on the next element twice.  I know this is not the right solution but it is solving my problem.